# For each in VBA - starting from third stylesheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've hot many stylesheets in Workbook in Excel and I need to make some changes in almost every stylesheet. First two of them and last few should be skipped.

I'm using For Each loop and really don't have idea how to skip 2 first elements. With the last ones is not problem, because I check the stylesheet's name and if it's equal to my condition I'm breaking the loop and exit.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    If ws.Name = "03.2016PTF" Then Exit For
    'here's my code
Next
```

If I will exit from loop at start I won't do changes in the rest of documents.

Comment: Are you referring to skipping sheets? `if not ws.Name = "03.2016PTF" and not ws.Name = "03.2017PTF" then `

Comment: Or lose the `Exit For` and change it so the if-statement becomes an `if-not "condition" then` which encloses the `'here's my code` section

Comment: No need to activate, nor to select (although you are not doing the latter)

Comment: @TimStack Unless the OP later uses `ActiveSheet` instead of `ws`.....

Comment: @Mistella Which I would not recommend them to do either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
With ThisWorkbook

maxsht = .Sheets.Count

For i = 3 To maxsht
    If .Sheets(i).Name = "03.2016PTF" Then Exit For
    'here's my code
Next i

End With
```

It loops through all sheets using the `Index`, so effectively you can start at the nth sheet, in this case the third.

The code loops until the last sheet in the `wb` unless it encounters the aforementioned sheet named `03.2016PTF`, at which the loop exits.

Comment: While you are supposing the sheets to skip are on the 2 first index, you are still using the if statement to exit the for in case one of the following sheets after the third is that one. He asked how to skip 2 sheets, you are ending the loop in case you find one.

Comment: @Damian I don't see the problem. OP wants to iterate all sheets except for the first n sheets, and end the loop as it encounters a certain named sheet. That's what my code does. Alternatively he could set the last index for the loop, but that won't change all too much.

Comment: OP wants to skip 2 sheets, you are ending the procedure if one (not the two he is asking) of the avoided sheets pop up on the iteration. So if `Sheets(3).Name = "03.2016PTF"`this macro does nothing.

Comment: Reading OP's post over and over again but can't see him mentioning he wants to end the loop if one of sheet names is encountered, just the one. "First two of them and last few should be skipped". 
No mention of a second sheet name. If the third sheet is named `03.2016PTF` and the loop ends, that is exactly what OP requested.

Comment: Here is another problem, I already used another For loop inside this For Each, now when I'm trying with your solution I got an error `For control variable already in use`

Comment: @paprykarz Try using `Next i` instead of `Next` in my code. I have edited my code. I always specify the object in the `Next` statement. It's good practice.

Comment: The problem was I had For loop with `i` also inside the loop in your example, I just changed your `i` to `j` and now it's working, thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Using `And` on the if statement to check for more criterias.

- `Or` any of them could trigger the if.
- `And` them all must be true so the if is triggered.

This way you can fill in as much sheets as you need and won't worry about their order.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, arrWs As Variant, Skiped As Boolean

arrWs = Array("Sheet1ToAvoid", "Sheet2ToAvoid", "...") 'fill this with as much sheets you need

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Skiped = Application.Match(ws.Name, arrWs, 0)
    If Not Skiped Then
        'here's my code
    End If
Next
```

Comment: But there's is around 30~ stylesheets to skip at the end so the conditions would be huge

Comment: Are you sure the final user won't ever move the sheets? Otherwise, you could just input all the names into an array and check just 1 condition.

Comment: As you see the name "03.2016PTF" its March 2016, I need to skip 2 first because these are summaries, and then are starting month from now, so "02.2019" (every month has 2 stylesheets), I need to change data in every month till May 2016, and there are 30-40 more months at the end that I need to skip.

Comment: @paprykarz I've edited my answer to hold all the sheets you need at once.